# django ajax call return 403 bad request

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to compile project https://github.com/kannan4k/django-carpool
please refer this project repo for this issue.

and end up with following error during ajax call.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (BAD REQUEST).

I know this is because of ajax post request & CSRF tokens.
following is my setting.
1. disable `"django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware"`
2. in new_trip page I have a button (Postdata)so this button sends an ajax request.

My View:-

```
@login_required
def save_journey(request):

    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
        try:
            res = json.loads(request.body)
            cords = res['cords']
            cords = [[x['d'], x['e']] for x in cords]
            distance = res['distance']
            start_place = res['start']
            end_place = res['end']
            clusters = clusterize_latlngs(cords, distance)
            time = datetime.datetime.strptime(res['time'], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
            Trip.objects.create(user=request.user, time=time, cluster=json.dumps(clusters), travel_distance=distance,
                                start_place=start_place, end_place=end_place)

            return HttpResponse()
        except:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['POST'])
```

Ajax call (home.js)

```
function postData() {
    radius = 0;
    var url = "/save_journey/";
    var dataType = 'json';
    if (type == 'r') {
        radius = $('#radius').val();
        url = "/get_results/";
        dataType = 'html';
    }

    var data = JSON.stringify({
        cords: myroute,
        time: document.getElementById('dateStart').value,
        start: document.getElementById('startPlace').innerHTML,
        end: document.getElementById('endPlace').innerHTML,
        radius: radius,
        distance: distance

    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: dataType,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            if (type == 'r') {
                window.location.href = "/search_results/";
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = '/trip_success/';
            }

        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('Error getting options list...')
        }
    });
    console.log(data);

}
```

this code is not able to call /save_journey/ URL.
I tried many answers from stack overflow & didn't figure out what is the problem .

Comment: It is very hard to figure out what is wrong because you are catching all exceptions and simply returning a `403` in your view. Print all the exceptions and update the question with appropriate details.

Comment: You're specifically telling your code to return Bad Request if any exception happens. By doing that, you've carefully hidden any information that would allow you or us to actually debug the problem. Remove that bare try/except.

Comment: @v1k45 :- Thanks for the comment. i can't post whole code here so please look at the repo :- https://github.com/kannan4k/django-carpool

when i visit /new_trip page there is a button which call PostData() method in home.js & it try to call /save_journey/ which leads to issue.

Comment: we are not asking for more code. just remove the try/except block and show us what errors you're getting.

Comment: @v1k45: without Try/except block it gives Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Comment: now use your browser's network tab and see what error you're getting from server and post that here

Answer (score 0):

You should never disable `csrftoken` unless you're absolutely sure about what you're doing. It's an important part of the security features implemented in Django.

Here is an example of how you can use Ajax with Django with `csrftoken`:

You can use Ajax Post to send `JSON` to Django and then handle the arguments as a `dict()`. Here is an example:

In browser (JQuery/JavaScript):

```
    function newModule() {

        var my_data = $("#my_element").val(); // Whatever value you want to be sent.

        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'modules' %}",       // Handler as defined in Django URLs. 
            type: "POST",                     // Method.
            dataType: "json",                 // Format as JSON (Default).
            data: {
                path: my_data,                // Dictionary key (JSON). 
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: 
                         '{{ csrf_token }}'   // Unique key.
            },

            success: function (json) {

                // On success do this.

            },

            error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {

                // On failure do this. 

            }

        });
```

In server engine (Python):

```
def handle(request):

    # Post request containing the key.  
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'my_data' in request.POST.keys():

        # Retrieving the value.
        my_data = request.POST['my_data']

    # ...
```

Hope this helps.